# Помогите разобраться со счетчиком

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть счетчик времени.помогите разобраться как изменить дату отсчета на 
**"до 31-го декабря осталось"**

Менял дату в строке '`ts = new Date(2018, 12, 31)`' но дата отображается некорректно.

```
(function($){

// Number of seconds in every time division
var days    = 24*60*60,
    hours   = 60*60,
    minutes = 60;

// Creating the plugin
$.fn.countdown = function(prop){

    var options = $.extend({
        callback    : function(){},
        timestamp   : 0
    },prop);

    var left, d, h, m, s, positions;

    // Initialize the plugin
    init(this, options);

    positions = this.find('.position');

    (function tick(){

        // Time left
        left = Math.floor((options.timestamp - (new Date())) / 1000);

        if(left < 0){
            left = 0;
        }

        // Number of days left
        d = Math.floor(left / days);
        updateDuo(0, 1, d);
        left -= d*days;

        // Number of hours left
        h = Math.floor(left / hours);
        updateDuo(2, 3, h);
        left -= h*hours;

        // Number of minutes left
        m = Math.floor(left / minutes);
        updateDuo(4, 5, m);
        left -= m*minutes;

        // Number of seconds left
        s = left;
        updateDuo(6, 7, s);

        // Calling an optional user supplied callback
        options.callback(d, h, m, s);

        // Scheduling another call of this function in 1s
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    })();

    // This function updates two digit positions at once
    function updateDuo(minor,major,value){
        switchDigit(positions.eq(minor),Math.floor(value/10)%10);
        switchDigit(positions.eq(major),value%10);
    }

    return this;
};


function init(elem, options){
    elem.addClass('countdownHolder');

    // Creating the markup inside the container
    $.each(['Days','Hours','Minutes','Seconds'],function(i){
        $('<span class="count'+this+'">').html(
            '<span class="position">\
                <span class="digit static">0</span>\
            </span>\
            <span class="position">\
                <span class="digit static">0</span>\
            </span>'
        ).appendTo(elem);

        if(this!="Seconds"){
            elem.append('<span class="countDiv countDiv'+i+'"></span>');
        }
    });

}

// Creates an animated transition between the two numbers
function switchDigit(position,number){

    var digit = position.find('.digit')

    if(digit.is(':animated')){
        return false;
    }

    if(position.data('digit') == number){
        // We are already showing this number
        return false;
    }

    position.data('digit', number);

    var replacement = $('<span>',{
        'class':'digit',
        css:{
            top:'-2.1em',
            opacity:0
        },
        html:number
    });

    // The .static class is added when the animation
    // completes. This makes it run smoother.

    digit
        .before(replacement)
        .removeClass('static')
        .animate({top:'2.5em',opacity:0},'fast',function(){
            digit.remove();
        })

    replacement
        .delay(100)
        .animate({top:0,opacity:1},'fast',function(){
            replacement.addClass('static');
        });
}
})(jQuery);
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

var note = $('#note'),
    ts = new Date(2018, 12, 31),
    newYear = true;

if((new Date()) > ts){
    // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
    // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
    ts = (new Date()).getTime() + 0*0*00*00*1000;
    newYear = false;
}

$('#countdown').countdown({
    timestamp   : ts,
    callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

        var message = "";

        message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
        message += hours + " hour" + ( hours==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
        message += minutes + " minute" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'s' ) + " and ";
        message += seconds + " second" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'s' ) + " <br />";

        if(newYear){
            message += "left until the new year!";
        }
        else {
            message += "left to 10 days from now!";
        }

        note.html(message);
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на [синтаксис](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) `new Date()` и [примичание](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) к параметру 
`monthIndex`.

> Note: The argument monthIndex is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11.

Это означает что индекс Января = 0, а индекс Декабря = 11. Для корректной даты вам нужно сделать изменение в этой строчке:

```
var note = $('#note'),
ts = new Date(2018, 11, 31),
```